# Iframe between header and footer

Tags: html, css, iframe

I was wondering how can I add an iframe between the header and the footer of my webpage, I mean in the blank between the header and footer. I tried height 100% but it overrides the header! I am using the template from http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/preview.html. Can anyone help please? Thanks

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: I added a link to the template

Comment: >*I tried height 100% but it overrides the header!*< We would like to see that. We would need an example that reproduces the issue at hand. Too many factors arise when we must fill in the gaps.

Comment: @zer00ne The website has many css, index and js. The template can be found at materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/preview.html. I can't post all the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an iframe in HTML between the header and footer, you will place this code, but change the source to whatever you want to point it to.

```
<iframe src="http://www.unlocktheinbox.com"></iframe>
```

The width and height, if set to 100% is going to be confined to the parent elements on you form, which looks like one of your DIV's.

So on your example page, remove this code.

Replace this code with.

```
<div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
        <div class="container">
          <br><br>
          <h1 class="header center orange-text">Starter Template</h1>
          <div class="row center">
            <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="row center">
            <a href="http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html" id="download-button" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Get Started</a>
          </div>
          <br><br>

        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="container">
        <div class="section">

          <!--   Icon Section   -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m4">
              <div class="icon-block">
                <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="material-icons">flash_on</i></h2>
                <h5 class="center">Speeds up development</h5>

                <p class="light">We did most of the heavy lifting for you to provide a default stylings that incorporate our custom components. Additionally, we refined animations and transitions to provide a smoother experience for developers.</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col s12 m4">
              <div class="icon-block">
                <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="material-icons">group</i></h2>
                <h5 class="center">User Experience Focused</h5>

                <p class="light">By utilizing elements and principles of Material Design, we were able to create a framework that incorporates components and animations that provide more feedback to users. Additionally, a single underlying responsive system across all platforms allow for a more unified user experience.</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col s12 m4">
              <div class="icon-block">
                <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></h2>
                <h5 class="center">Easy to work with</h5>

                <p class="light">We have provided detailed documentation as well as specific code examples to help new users get started. We are also always open to feedback and can answer any questions a user may have about Materialize.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div class="section">

        </div>
      </div>
```

With

```
 <iframe src="http://www.unlocktheinbox.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: The iframe should be filling the blank between the header and footer. Your code gives a square and the webpage in it...

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `position` and `top` to position the iFrame below the header. 
Try using

```
position:absolute;
top:65px;
left:0px;
```

See here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I'll try that, thanks

Comment: Please upvote if my answer helped you :)

Comment: I am less than 15 reputation because this is my 2nd post here so I can't but I will accept it... Also I have found the answer